# Sumar valores de la tabla mysql si cumple con una condicion

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy realizando una consulta en *mysql* y quiero que me traiga los valores sumados de mi tabla por defectos.

Así tengo mi base de datos y, si vemos en el defecto pelo, está en la planta de *Mastrotto* y de *Gestamp (Producción)*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es la suma pero si tienen diferentes plantas se sumen por separado, tendría que tener en *Matrotto* 5 de pelo y en *Gestamp (Produccion)* solo 2, pero me los suma aunque sean de distintas plantas y me da 7 en el defecto de PELO. Necesito que es si es distinta la plana se sumen aparte.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
$sql = 'SELECT planta, defecto, sum(scrap) as TOTAL from datos group by defecto having count(*) > 1';
```

Comment: ¿Intentaste agrupar por defecto y planta? `GROUP BY defecto, planta`

Comment: Intenta usar los `WHEN CASE` en la sentencia SQL. [Link](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/sentencia-case-en-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

Podrias hacer dos consultas SQL por separado
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM datos WHERE planta LIKE '%Mastrotto%'";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM datos WHERE planta LIKE '%Gestamp%'";